# Visual Studio 2017 does not show properties of VS 2010 projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2017

The software project I am working on was started many years ago in VS2010. I loaded the solution in VS2017 because I wanted to benefit from its features. I declined to migrate it, because the projects should still be compiled using VS2010's compiler.

Working in and editing the solution in VS2017 was fine until I made the blunder of adding a project from VS2017's GUI. Once the project was created and added to the solution I could not open the properties of any VS2010 project: "There are no property pages for the selection". ONly the VS2017 project properties are accessible.

Removing the new project did not fix it, neither did rebuilding the solution from its make files nor Reset All Settings from Tools->Import and Export settings. However, the project properties are accessible when opening th solution in VS2010.

It looks like this is a bug in VS2017 but since it worked before, I am looking for a workaround. Is there a way to reset (preferable without having to reinstall) VS 2017 so I loads the solution completely fresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with VS2010 (French) installed with VS2017.

When I set the VS2017 IDE in English, the Project Properties page is empty for the VS2010 project.

I changed the VS2017 IDE Language settings to same as Windows (=French) and after a restart of the IDE, the project properties are displayed again.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: you're right. I forgot that I changed the language from german to english. When I changed it back, properties were back. The project I added had nothing to do with it. Obviously still a bug though.